# How define "ACCESS_TOKEN" in a .env file in the project gitlab

Tags: python, gitlab

I am trying to access gitlab from python. I have code for gitlab but when I try to add access token in gitlab my way on screenshot is not working. How do I need to define "ACCESS_TOKEN" in a .env file in the project gitlab??
(Before I created this access token in gitlab)

[image]

```
import gitlab
import os
from envparse import env

if os.path.isfile('.env'):
    env.read_envfile()

ACCESS_TOKEN = env('ACCESS_TOKEN')

gl = gitlab.Gitlab('https://gitlab.com/', ACCESS_TOKEN)


def get_projects():
    projects = gl.projects.list(owned=True)
    for project in projects:
        print(project.name)


def main():
    get_projects()


main()
```

Answer (score 0):

ACCESS_TOKEN is to be set in the environment variables.
for linux, this can be set by "export NAME=VALUE" (temporary)
for persisted, you can set it in /.bash_profile of the user

for windows,

1. right-click the Windows icon and select System.
2. In the Settings window, under Related Settings, click Advanced system settings.
   You can see "Environment Variables" button, click on it, and add/modify the variable with same name.